# Ajax doesnot take string or values with special characters

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

in my  form i want to FETCH item description using item code for example i have item description as 24"STUB END 316L SCH10S and its item code is STUB316LS10SW  so when i search in item code field using STUB316LS10SW  the item description for that specific item code is not fetching because in item description i have 24" ie special characters so the ajax is not fetching item description ..can you please help on this

```
         $(function() {
         function log( message ) {
         $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
          $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
         }
        $("#itemcode1").autocomplete({
         source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "getProductList.php",
        dataType: "json",
     data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term
      },
     success: function( data ) {
      response($.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {


      return {
      label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") ,
     value: item.nameval,
     value1: item.toponymName,
     price:item.price,
     quantity:item.quantity,
     prodId:item.prodId,
      itemcode:item.itemcode,
    }
    }));
   }
   });
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style1">
          <tr>
            <td>Item Code </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="itemcode1" name="itemcode1"  /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td width="125">Products/Description</td>
        <td width="10">:</td>
        <td width="175"><input name="productDesc1" type="text"  id="productDesc1"></td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" 
        style="width:100px;" id="crt"></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but i think your php script might have a different character encoding than your `<meta charset=''>`. try to synchronize, let know if it worked.

Comment: I haven't got a CLUE what you're talking about... Please improve your question.

Comment: when i search for item description using the item code i dont get item description which have special characters in it@kuro @dennis haarbink...@kuro do you want me to try changing the meta characterset to what ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap values (or everything) with special characters into `encodeURI()` function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

To decode in JS use: `decodeURI()` function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

To decode in PHP use `rawurldecode()` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

use this and encode your **description** this will accept ur special character..you may searching for this not sure what actually you want

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

or

```
string rawurlencode ( string $str )
```

improve your question... it's difficult to understand

Comment: i have improved my question please let me know if you need me to explain @Prafulla